# can i divert text output ( cat() &/or print() ) to a separate window

Tags: r

platform:  R 2.14.2   -    Windows XP

When I use cat()  or print()  in a script, the output text is of course 
interlaced with the lines of the script.

I can  sink()  the output to a textfile and then play the file back at the 
end of the script, but that's not really what I'm after.

It would be nice if the lines of text output could appear in a separate 
window,  in the same sort of way that you'd use  windows() for graphical 
output.

Apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

```
    Bob Kinley
```

Comment: I suspect this may be possible with some tcltk magic.

Comment: Maybe possible using `socketConnection` with `sink`, see `?connections`

Comment: Following up on Roman's comment. Here is some not so magic magic using the `gWidgets` package (which can use tcltk if desired): `library(gWidgets); output <- gtext(cont=gwindow("log messages")); log_it <- function(msg) insert(output, msg)` Now just use `log_it`.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to send the output of `cat` to a file so you'll have two separated outputs:

```
cat(42,file='aFile.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/

This will enable you to monitor a file continuously and print as it changes.